# How to make a join with ON in jpa? ( Spring Data Jpa 1.4 )

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have this query, which I have tried in SQL and it goes perfectly

```
@Query("SELECT new es.abacor.elser.commons.empleado.EmpleadoList("+ 
        "empleado.id,persona.nombre,persona.apellido1,persona.apellido2,persona.dni,persona.email)" + 
        " FROM rrhh.empleado as empleado" + 
        " INNER JOIN commons.persona AS persona ON empleado.persona_comun = persona.id" + 
        " WHERE" + 
        " empleado.persona_comun is not null" + 
        " and empleado.borrador = false" + 
        " and empleado.deleted is null" + 
        " and empleado.fecha_fin_contrato is null" + 
        " order by persona.nombre,persona.apellido1,persona.apellido2 asc")
public List<EmpleadoList> allEmpleadosList();
```

But I get the following error when executing within my project

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 217 [SELECT new es.abacor.elser.commons.empleado.EmpleadoList(empleado.id,persona.nombre,persona.apellido1,persona.apellido2,persona.dni,persona.email) FROM rrhh.empleado as empleado INNER JOIN commons.persona AS persona ON empleado.persona_comun = persona.id WHERE empleado.persona_comun is not null and empleado.borrador = false and empleado.deleted is null and empleado.fecha_fin_contrato is null order by persona.nombre,persona.apellido1,persona.apellido2 asc]
```

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong, I do not know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0):

JPA doesn't work on tables, it works on objects. If you want to use native queries you have to add `nativeQuery=true` to the Definition:

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, <SQL-Statement>)
```

otherwise the `ON` clasue will be generated from the annotations in your entities